# Create task and change the opportunity stage when quote is updated to particular status via mail

Tags: visual-workflow, opportunity, quote

A task needs to be created when quote status is changed to 'Sent' (status is not changed manually but via mail). Also when status is changed to 'Accepted' or 'Denied' opportunity stage should be Closed Won or Closed Lost
When Accept is clicked - quote status is Accepted, Deny - Denied and Call Back - Sent.
[image]

I created this flow and only the opp stage is changing but it is not creating a task.
[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

Any ideas on how to solve this? Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to debug the flow and check where exactly it is failing. Can you share the Debug screenshots as well.

Comment: When I am trying to debug - with changing each quote status and testing it everything is completed successfully, when I change the quote statuses manually - again it is working correctly, the opp stage changes or the task is creating. Only when I am clicking the call back button in the mail - the task it is not created,